# Как проверить наличие заглавных букв?

Tags: mysql, sql

Надо найти все записи в столбце таблицы которые содержат заглавные буквы. Столбец текстовый (varchar). MySql 5.7.23. Пытался `where field regexp '[A-Z]'`, но почему то так находит записи без учета регистра. Т.е. просто все записи в которых есть буквы.

Comment: По умолчанию строки в `MySQL` нечувствительны к регистру. Попробуйте бинарные строки (`WHERE BINARY field REGEXP...`). Не помню, право, работает ли это с регулярками, проверьте)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov да, спасибо. Это сработало!

Comment: отлично, тогда чуть позже напишу полноценный ответ)